# Maxent error : java.lang.NumberFormatException : For input string « nan »

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, error, ascii, maxent

I'm doing predictive distributions for some species using Maxent and QGIS. I downloaded my environemental data from : https://worldclim.org/data/cmip6/cmip6_clim30s.html
They are multibands data so I rearanged the bands to clip the raster by mask layer.
Then converted all the freshly generated raster into ascII but when running in Maxent I get this issue :

> Maxent error : java.lang.NumberFormatException : For input string « nan »

I checked the proprieties using GDAL and they are for good in ASCII and not in GeoTIFF (which is a common solution for this error).

> GDAL Driver Description    AAIGrid
>
> GDAL Driver Metadata   Arc/Info ASCII Grid

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: I'm not using code, only Maxent : https://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/maxent/

Comment: then it seems you will need to clean your input data, replace the NaN with your preferred No Data value

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand how, I downloaded the rasters from a website as mentioned. I do not know how to add a value to the rasters.

Comment: You have an ascii grid file so you can edit them in any standard editor

Comment: OK, thanks for your anwser, this is sadly out of my competences range.